# How do I query all rows within a 5-mile radius of my coordinates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgis

Here's a sample of my PostgreSQL in CSV format.

```
row,latitude,longitude
1,42.082513,-72.621498
2,42.058588,-72.633386
3,42.061118,-72.631541
4,42.06035,-72.634145
```

I have thousands more rows like these spanning coordinates across the world.

I want to query the table only for coordinates within a certain radius. How do I do this with PostGIS and PostgreSQL?

Comment: You want a K-nearest-neighbour (KNN) search using a GiST or GIN index.

Comment: @CraigRinger I've never done anything involving either of those. Where can I learn more?

Comment: You have your data in a CSV formatted file or in a table with data like this from a file in CSV format? You are looking for "coordinates within a certain radius". From a specific location or do you want a solution for any location (e.g. a function with parameters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a combo of Erwin's and Patrick's answers.

```
-- Add geography column
ALTER TABLE googleplaces ADD COLUMN gps geography;
UPDATE googleplaces SET gps = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
CREATE INDEX googleplaces_gps ON googleplaces USING gist(gps);

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(gps, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-72.657, 42.0657), 4326), 5 * 1609);
```

Answer (score 12):

You want *"all rows within a 5-mile radius of a coordinate"*, so this is *not* exactly a [K-nearest-neighbour (KNN) problem](http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/). Related, but your case is simpler. *"Find the 10 rows closest to my coordinates"* would be a KNN problem.

Convert your coordinates to `geography` values:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326)::geography
```

Alternatively you could use the simpler `geometry` type. Consider:
[4.2.2. When to use Geography Data type over Geometry data type](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry)

Then we have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, geog geography NOT NULL
);
```

All you need is [**`ST_DWithin()`**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) - and a **spatial index** to make it fast:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_geog_gist ON tbl USING gist(geog);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance(c.x, geog) AS distance  -- distance is optional
FROM   tbl t, (SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-72.63 42.06)')) AS c(x)
WHERE  ST_DWithin(c.x, geog, 8045)  -- distance in meter
ORDER  BY distance; -- order is optional, you did not ask for that
```

*Or* you can use your original columns and create a functional index ...
This and other details in this closely related answer on dba.SE:

- [Order by distance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60711/3684)

Answer (score 4):

You should first create a table from your CSV formatted file, using the [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) (if the file is accessible to the PostgreSQL **server**) or the [`\copy` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) in `psql` if the file is not local to the server. See other Q+A on SO for examples if you have any trouble.

Once you have your data in a table, you should convert your `longitude` and `latitude` columns to the PostGIS `geography` type by adding a column to your table of type `geography(POINT, 4326)` and then populating that column (here called `gps`) with the appropriate values:

```
UPDATE my_table SET gps = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

Add an index on that column to allow for efficient searches:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_gps ON my_table USING gist(gps);
```

You can now find the rows within 5 miles from a given location, e.g. `(-72.657, 42.0657)`, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ST_DWithin(gps, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-72.657, 42.0657), 4326), 5 * 1609);
```

Note that `ST_DWithin()` on a `geography` column will work in meters, so you have to multiply your radius in miles with the 1,609 meters in a mile.