# How to lookup based on ranged values

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

I have a table like:

```
id          name
001to005    ABC
006to210    PQR
211to300    XYZ
```

This is not the final table i can make it any how i want...so i would like to lookup on this data on id and extract name like if id is in range of 001-005 then ABC and if id is in range 006-010 .... then name XYZ.

My approach would be, store id as regular expression in table like this:

```
id                 name
[0][0][1-5]        ABC
[0-2][0-9][0-9]    PQR
[2-3][0-9][0-9]    XYZ
```

and then query:

```
select * from table where '004' ~ id
```

This query will return ABC which is correct but when range gets bigger my input value can lie on both 2nd and 3rd row. 
For Eg:

```
select * from table where '299' ~ id
```

this query will result in 2 rows,so my question is what reg exp to use to make it more restrictive or is there any other approach to solve this:

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Answer (score 3):

Do *not* store regular expressions for simple ranges, that would be extremely expensive and cannot use an index: every single expression in the table would have to be evaluated for every query to satisfy conditions.

You could use [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) like [@a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183252/how-to-lookup-based-on-ranged-values#comment85372496_49183252). But while you don't need the added [functionality for range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) this simple layout is smaller and faster:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   id_lo int NOT NULL
 , id_hi int NOT NULL
 , name text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
  (  1,   5, 'ABC')
, (  6, 210, 'PQR')
, (211, 300, 'XYZ');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON t (id_lo, id_hi DESC);
```

Two `integer` occupy 8 bytes, `int4range` value occupies 17 bytes. Size matters in tables and indexes.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  4 BETWEEN id_lo AND id_hi;
```

Lower (`id_lo`) and upper (`id_hi`) bounds are *included* in the range like your sample data suggests.
Note that range types *exclude* the upper bound by default.

Also assuming that leading zeros are insignificant, so we can operate with plain `integer`.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL daterange not using index correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824314/postgresql-daterange-not-using-index-correctly/22824761#22824761)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)
- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480715/find-overlapping-date-ranges-in-postgresql/15305292#15305292)

To enforce distinct ranges in the table:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

You still don't need a range type in the table for this:

- [Postgres: How to find nearest tsrange from timestamp outside of ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208541/postgres-how-to-find-nearest-tsrange-from-timestamp-outside-of-ranges/41210948#41210948)