# How can I get all the related rows when using IN to filter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgis

This is what my query looks like:

```
select "spaces"."id" as "id",
  "spaces"."user_id" as "user_id",
  "spaces"."type" as "type",
  "spaces"."latitude" as "latitude",
  "spaces"."longitude" as "longitude",
  "categories"."category_id" as "categories:category_id"
  from "spaces"
  left join "spaces_categories" as "categories" on "categories"."space_id" = "spaces"."id"
  where "categories"."category_id" in ($)
  and ST_DWithin(spaces.geometry::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point($,$), 4326)::geography, $)
```

I am using pg 14.1

I am trying to find all spaces within a radius that meet the requested category Ids, along with all the categories for those spaces.

A space can have many category IDs, so if I search for category ids `(1,2)`, and there happens to be 2 space results (and assume each space has 4 categories, `1,2,3,4`), I would be expecting 8 rows.  However, my query only returns 4 rows, for categories 1,2.

How can I update my query so I can get all the categories, as long there is some overlap?

Is it due to my `IN` clause?

Comment: The query is malformed. The predicate `where "categories"."category_id" in ($)` silently converts the outer join into an inner join. Please modify the query by either 1) using an inner join, or 2) by accepting nulls in `"categories"."category_id"`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but can you please explain what you mean by modify the query? Are you saying to move the where one down (before the postgis function), and use and so it is on the join?

Comment: `I am trying to find spaces within a radius, and that meet some categories input.` is not the same as `get all the categories, as long there is some overlap`. Please clarify what you want *exactly*. Start by disclosing your Postgres version.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And `EXISTS` subquery should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT s.id
     , s.user_id
     , s.type
     , s.latitude
     , s.longitude
     , c.category_id AS "categories:category_id"
FROM   spaces                 s
LEFT   JOIN spaces_categories c ON c.space_id = s.id
WHERE  st_dwithin(s.geometry::geography, st_setsrid(st_point($,$), 4326)::geography, $)
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM spaces_categories x
   WHERE  x.space_id = s.id
   AND    x.category_id IN ($)
   );
```

There are many other ways, but this should be fastest and clearest.

The cast from `geometry` to `geography` seems worrisome for performance, though. Do you have an expression **index** covering that?

Related:

- [How do I query all rows within a 5-mile radius of my coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575912/how-do-i-query-all-rows-within-a-5-mile-radius-of-my-coordinates/32576354#32576354)
- [How to find intersecting geographies between two tables recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899565/how-to-find-intersecting-geographies-between-two-tables-recursively/42046988#42046988)
- [Why is my spatial query slower in Postgres 13 than in Postgres 11?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300294/3684)
- [ST_DWithin Calc Meters - transform or cast?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222281/7244)

Comment: Thank you! The cast from geometry to geography is because I had not understood postgis, I should have used geography column since I am going to be doing queries to find within meters of a point, or within bounding box. The geometry allow me to query in degrees. Do you think it is better that I change the column? I don't have expression index, only a column gist index.

Comment: If you can, switch to `geography`. If you can't, at least add one ore more expression indexes to cover your main queries. I added related links. The plain index you have is not going to help the query at hand.